# QtQuick2 Shortcut not triggered

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I'm adding keyboard shortcuts to a QtQuick Controls2 application using Qt 5.8.0 and I would like to control a tab bar using QKeySequence like this:

```
ApplicationWindow {
  ...
  Shortcut {
      sequence: StandardKey.NextChild
      onActivated: tabBar.nextTab()
  }

  Shortcut {
      sequence: StandardKey.PreviousChild
      onActivated: tabBar.previousTab()
  }
}

TabBar {
  id: tabBar
  ...
  function nextTab() {
    console.log("next tab")
    if((currentIndex + 1) < contentChildren.length)
      currentIndex += 1
    else
      currentIndex = 0
  }

  function previousTab() {
    console.log("previous tab")
    if((currentIndex - 1) > 0)
      currentIndex -= 1
    else
      currentIndex = contentChildren.length - 1
  }
}
```

This works for the NextChild sequence using Ctrl+Tab, however the PreviousChild sequence does not work. I checked the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeysequence.html) and it claims in Windows the previousChild sequence is Ctrl+Shift+Tab, as I would have expected.

I added a `console.log()` to check, whether the function gets called which it doesn't.
Since I am using identical code for both functions I can only assume the key sequence is wrong, or is there anything else I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a Qt Bug 
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-15746

Alternatively, you can define your previousChild shortcut as

```
Shortcut {
    sequence:  "Ctrl+Shift+Tab"
    onActivated: {
        tabBar.previousTab()
    }
}
```

That is beside the point but there is a small index bug in your `previousTab` implementation

```
function previousTab() {
    console.log("previous tab")
    if(currentIndex > 0) // Instead of (currentIndex - 1) > 0
        currentIndex--
    else
        currentIndex = contentChildren.length-1
}
```